# asp.net changing password format problem

Tags: asp.net, passwords, asp.net-membership

i changed my password format in the web.config for hashed to encrypted and added a machine key but after that i got this error :

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0
```

i tried changing back to hashed but i still got this error.

here is the membership code:

```
        <membership>
        <providers>
            <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
                 type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                 connectionString="LocalSqlServer"
                 enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                 enablePasswordReset="true"
                 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                 applicationName="/"
                 requiresUniqueEmail="true"
                 minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
                 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                 passwordFormat="Encrypted"
                 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                 passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                 passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>    
    </membership>
```

and connection string:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=AHMED-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**note: the connection string was working fine before i changed the password format.**

*using asp.net 4.0*

what is the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by attaching the ASPNETDB.MDF file and removing the Initial Catalog from the connection string:

```
      <connectionStrings>
   <remove name="localsqlserver"/>
        <add name="localsqlserver" connectionString="Data Source=AHMED-PC\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```